# What's the proper way to associate a mutex with its data?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

In the classic problem of transferring money from one bank account to another, the accepted solution (I believe) is to associate a mutex with each bank account, then lock both before withdrawing the money from one account and depositing it into the other. At first blush, I'd do it like this:

```
class Account {
public:
  void deposit(const Money& amount);
  void withdraw(const Money& amount);
  void lock() { m.lock(); }
  void unlock() { m.unlock(); }

private:
  std::mutex m;
};

void transfer(Account& src, Account& dest, const Money& amount)
{
  src.lock();
  dest.lock();

  src.withdraw(amount);
  dest.deposit(amount);

  dest.unlock();
  src.unlock();
}
```

But the manual unlocking smells.  I could make the mutex public, then use `std::lock_guard` in `transfer`, but public data members smell, too.

The requirements for `std::lock_guard` are that its type satisfy the *BasicLockable* requirements, which is just that calls to `lock` and `unlock` are valid. `Account` satisfies that requirement, so I could just use `std::lock_guard` with `Account` directly:

```
void transfer(Account& src, Account& dest, const Money& amount)
{
  std::lock_guard<Account> g1(src);
  std::lock_guard<Account> g2(dest);

  src.withdraw(amount);
  dest.deposit(amount);
}
```

This seems okay, but I've never seen this kind of thing done before, and duplicating the locking and unlocking of a mutex in `Account` seems kind of smelly in its own right.

What's the best way to associate a mutex with the data it's protecting in a scenario like this?

UPDATE: In comments below, I noted that `std::lock` can be used to avoid deadlock, but I overlooked that `std::lock` relies on the existence of `try_lock` functionality (in addition to that for `lock` and `unlock`).  Adding `try_lock` to `Account`'s interface seems like a fairly gross hack. It thus seems that if the mutex for an `Account` object is to remain in `Account`, it has to be public.  Which has quite the stench.

Some proposed solutions have clients use wrapper classes to silently associate mutexes with an `Account` object, but, as I've noted in my comments, this seems to make it easy for different parts of the code to use different wrapper objects around `Account`, each creating its own mutex, and that means that different parts of the code may attempt to lock the `Account` using different mutexes.  That's bad.

Other proposed solutions rely on locking only a single mutex at a time.  That eliminates the need to lock more than one mutex, but at the cost of making it possible for some threads to see inconsistent views of the system.  In essence, this abandons transactional semantics for operations involving multiple objects.

At this point, a public mutex is beginning to look like the least stinky of the available options, and that's a conclusion I really don't want to come to. Is there really nothing better?

Comment: Just do what the banks do, and wing it.

Comment: If you are only transferring money, you could forego the locks, and use atomic decrement and atomic increment on the balance. Make sure to bill the customer if there is an overdraft.

Comment: @user315052: You need the withdrawal and the deposit to be a single transaction. You can't get that with a single atomic operation.

Comment: All your examples have deadlock in case `transfer(a,b,x)` and `transfer(b,a,x)` happen at the same time. You need to lock in consistent order.

Comment: You also have UB if `transfer(a, a, x)` happens.

Comment: @zch: You're right, and I could solve that by using `std::lock` to lock the mutexes.  But before I approach that, I'd like to know what the best way is to associate the mutexes with their data.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: I question the requirement that it needs to be a single transaction.

Comment: @user315052, accounting requirement; basic one at that.

Comment: @JesseGood: Yes, you're right, but my question is about how to associate the mutex with its data, not how to write a bulletproof `transfer`.  Assuming the mutex is needed to solve this problem, I'd like to get the basics of my data structure resolved before focusing on the details of the transfer function.

Comment: @vonbrand: When I go to a bank to do a transfer, it is always done as two transactions.

Comment: @zch, the trick the Linux kernel uses is to lock in increasing address order. You could e.g. always lock in increasing account number order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out **Herb Sutter** talk at **C++ and Beyond 2012**: [C++ Concurrency](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism). He shows example of [Monitor Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29)-like implementation in C++11.

```
monitor<Account> m[2];
transaction([](Account &x,Account &y)
{
    // Both accounts are automaticaly locked at this place.
    // Do whatever operations you want to do on them.
    x.money-=100;
    y.money+=100;
},m[0],m[1]);
// transaction - is variadic function template, it may accept many accounts
```

Implementation:

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de69939cf1ec890d)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <ostream>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

typedef int Money;

struct Account
{
    Money money = 1000;
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
T &lvalue(T &&t)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
class monitor
{
    mutable mutex m;
    mutable T t;
public:
    template<typename F>
    auto operator()(F f) const -> decltype(f(t))
    {
        return lock_guard<mutex>(m),
               f(t);
    }
    template<typename F,typename ...Ts> friend
    auto transaction(F f,const monitor<Ts>& ...ms) ->
        decltype(f(ms.t ...))
    {
        return lock(lvalue(unique_lock<mutex>(ms.m,defer_lock))...),
        f(ms.t ...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    monitor<Account> m[2];

    transaction([](Account &x,Account &y)
    {
        x.money-=100;
        y.money+=100;
    },m[0],m[1]);

    for(auto &&t : m)
        cout << t([](Account &x){return x.money;}) << endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
900
1100
```

Comment: I think this code, in and of itself, can deadlock if money is transferred from A to B and from B to A at the same time.  My code has the same problem, but, as I noted in a comment above, it can be easily eliminated by using `std::lock`.  That doesn't seem to be possible here, because there is no part of the code that knows that two mutexes need to be locked.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe, I do use **std::lock** "lock(lvalue(unique_lock<mutex>(ms.m,defer_lock))...)". **transaction** function knows that two mutexes should be locked. (it is updated answer version)

Comment: In concept, I like what you're doing here, but it will take me a bit of time to really think it through. I like the generalization of `transaction` to work with an arbitrary number of objects, but I think there may be some details to tidy up as regards `const` correctness (e.g., it looks to me like `ms` should be passed as lref-to-`const`.  I plan to follow up again tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, const would be good addition - as we already have **mutable**.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because the design is consistent with the monitor approach that seems to be the consensus solution to the problem I originally posted about, plus this design is the only one that seems to easily extend to support transactions on multiple objects (monitors). It's interesting to note that that support is missing from the cited design that Herb Sutter shows in his referenced presentation.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with having the money "in flight" for a while. Make it like so:

```
Account src, dst;

dst.deposit(src.withdraw(400));
```

Now just make each individual method thread-safe, e.g.

```
int Account::withdraw(int n)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(m_);
    balance -= n;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: @0x499602D2: Change it. You need a way to communicate if the withdrawal isn't possible anyway.

Comment: The problem with this kind of solution is that it permits other threads to get an inconsistent view of the system.  After `withdraw` returns but before `deposit` begins, other threads can see a system where the accounting doesn't balance: money has disappeared from the system. This may be acceptable in some circumstances, but, in general, it's unlikely to be considered correct.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: Yep. That's the nature of a concurrent economy. You can't do a census without stopping everything.

Comment: @KerrekSB: For purposes of this discussion, please assume I don't want other threads to see inconsistent views of the system.

Comment: Two get consistency, you can create an intermediate object, say `Transfer`, that has its own lock. A `withdraw()` locks the `Transfer` object and places funds in it. A `deposit()` takes funds from the `Transfer` object, and then unlocks it. All views are consistent if the `Transfer` objects are part of the global view.

Comment: That works until sombody changes the code to: `int get = src.withdraw(400); SaveTransact(get,src,dst); dst.deposit(get);` Now when `SaveTransact()` throws 400 bobits have disappeared into the ether. You need to make the transfer atomic and locked and safe from being accidentally broken.

Comment: @user315052: If multiple, separate transactions are happening concurrently in your world, then you can't perform a complete census unless you lock *everything*. Just securing a single transaction isn't really making a difference.

Comment: @user315052: Moving money from one account into the transfer object such that no other thread sees an inconsistent view of the system is the original problem. I don't believe there is a way to solve this using only `std::atomic` operations. You need transactional semantics for the full withdrawal-deposit operation.

Comment: The solution I am advocating is exactly analogous to depositing a check. I believe whatever consistency rules you want to apply should match what banks actually use. If you are actually trying to solve a different problem than the banking model, then I am open to what that problem is.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: That's true, but I would like to argue that this isn't really a problem, since no observer can possibly observe two accounts at once, atomically, unless you somehow design your system for that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: In the code you posted, an arbitrary amount of computation may take place between the return of `withdraw` and the execution of `deposit`.  For example, the thread executing that code may be suspended to permit other threads to run. During this time, observers may examine as many accounts as they like.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: But not *consistently*. You can look at account A, and then at B, but in the meantime, any number of other threads may have modified A. So you can't hope to get a consistent snapshot, *ever*. So I say, don't bother trying to allow for one. (Imagine if you wanted to compare *three* accounts, and so forth.)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use a non-intrusive wrapper class instead of polluting the original object with a mutex and locking it on each method call. This wrapper class (which I named `Protected<T>`) contains the user object as a private variable. `Protected<T>` grants friendship to another class called `Locker<T>`. The locker takes the wrapper as its constructor argument and provides public accessor methods to the user object. The locker also keeps the wrapper's mutex locked during its lifetime. So the locker's lifetime defines a scope where the original object can be accessed in a safe way.

The `Protected<T>` can implement `operator->` to enable quickly calling a single method.

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>


template<typename>
struct Locker;


template<typename T>
struct Protected
{
    template<typename ...Args>
    Protected(Args && ...args) :
        obj_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {        
    }

    Locker<const T> operator->() const;
    Locker<T> operator->();

private:    
    friend class Locker<T>;
    friend class Locker<const T>;
    mutable std::mutex mtx_;
    T obj_;
};


template<typename T>
struct Locker
{
    Locker(Protected<T> & p) :
        lock_(p.mtx_),
        obj_(p.obj_)
    {
        std::cout << "LOCK" << std::endl;
    }

    Locker(Locker<T> && rhs) = default;

    ~Locker()
    {
        std::cout << "UNLOCK\n" << std::endl;
    }

    const T& get() const { return obj_; }
    T& get() { return obj_; }

    const T* operator->() const { return &get(); }
    T* operator->() { return &get(); }

private:    
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_;
    T & obj_;    
};


template<typename T>
struct Locker<const T>
{
    Locker(const Protected<T> & p) :
        lock_(p.mtx_),
        obj_(p.obj_)
    {
        std::cout << "LOCK (const)" << std::endl;
    }

    Locker(Locker<const T> && rhs) = default;

    ~Locker()
    {
        std::cout << "UNLOCK (const)\n" << std::endl;
    }

    const T& get() const { return obj_; }    
    const T* operator->() const { return &get(); }

private:    
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_;
    const T & obj_;
};


template<typename T>
Locker<T> Protected<T>::operator->()
{
    return Locker<T>(const_cast<Protected<T>&>(*this));
}


template<typename T>
Locker<const T> Protected<T>::operator->() const
{
    return Locker<T>(const_cast<Protected<T>&>(*this));
}

struct Foo
{
    void bar() { std::cout << "Foo::bar()" << std::endl; }
    void car() const { std::cout << "Foo::car() const" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Protected<Foo> foo;

    // Using Locker<T> for rw access
    {
        Locker<Foo> locker(foo);
        Foo & foo = locker.get();
        foo.bar();
        foo.car();
    }

    // Using Locker<const T> for const access
    {
        Locker<const Foo> locker(foo);
        const Foo & foo = locker.get();
        foo.car();
    }


    // Single actions can be performed quickly with operator-> 
    foo->bar();
    foo->car();
}
```

Which generates this output:

```
LOCK
Foo::bar()
Foo::car() const
UNLOCK

LOCK (const)
Foo::car() const
UNLOCK (const)

LOCK
Foo::bar()
UNLOCK

LOCK
Foo::car() const
UNLOCK
```

[Test with online compiler.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c3c08cda10533b8a6e52963083262350-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

**Update:** fixed const correctness.

**PS:** There's also an [asynchronous variant](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=665ae867f4fd7a82d9c8ff461c46dcb6).

Comment: This is an interesting design, but two things make me uncomfortable. First, if I have an `Account` I want to work on, `Protected<Account>` won't do the trick, because it will work on a *copy* of the `Account`.  That can be addressed by holding a reference instead of an object, but then you have the problem that different scopes might create different `Locker<Account>` objects for the same `Account` object, and then you have multiple mutexes for a single object.

Comment: This solution requires that the object is originally defined as `Protected<Account>`. The locker doesn't create any mutexes. However, creating multiple locker objects for the same protected object in the same scope will result in deadlock (unless you change the mutex type in the locker class to be recursive).

Comment: I think this fails to address the deadlock problem. If I want to work on two `Protected<Account>` objects `a` and `b`, and in one thread I create a `Locker` for `a` first and for `b` second, then in another thread I create a `Locker` for `b` first and for `a` second, I'll have deadlock.  I don't see a way to use `std::lock` to solve this problem, because there is no function that knows that more than one lock needs to be acquired. Am I missing something?

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe inconsistent lock ordering is the core problem here.

Comment: Right, and `std::lock` is supposed to be the solution. But to use it, you have to have access to all the locks at once.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I am a fan of the [LockingPtr](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766) paradigm (this article is quite outdated and I won't personally follow all of its advice) :

```
struct thread_safe_account_pointer {
     thread_safe_account_pointer( std::mutex & m,Account * acc) : _acc(acc),_lock(m) {}

     Account * operator->() const {return _acc;}
     Account& operator*() const {return *_acc;}
private:
     Account * _acc;
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _lock;
};
```

And implement the classes which contains an `Account` object like this:

```
class SomeTypeWhichOwnsAnAccount {
public:
     thread_safe_account_pointer get_and_lock_account() const {return thread_safe_account_pointer(mutex,&_impl);}

      //Optional non thread-safe
      Account* get_account() const {return &_impl;}

      //Other stuff..
private:
     Account _impl;
     std::mutex mutex;
};
```

Pointers may be replaced with smart pointers if suitable, and you will probably need a `const_thread_safe_account_pointer` (or even better a general purpose template `thread_safe_pointer` class)

Why is this better than monitors (IMO)?

1. You can design your Account class without thinking about thread-safety; thread-safety is a property of the object which *uses* your class, not of your class itself.
2. No need for recursive mutexes when nesting calls to member functions in your class.
3. You document clearly in your code whether you are locking a mutex or not (and you can prevent completely using-without-locking by not implementing `get_account`). Having both a `get_and_lock()` and a `get()` function *forces* you to think about thread-safety.
4. When defining functions (global or member), you have a clean semantic to specify whether a function requires the object's mutex to be locked (just pass a `thread_safe_pointer`) or is thread-safety-agnostic (use `Account&`).
5. Last but not least, `thread_safe_pointer` has a quite different semantic from monitors:

Consider a `MyVector` class which implements thread-safety via monitors, and the following code:

```
MyVector foo;
// Stuff.. , other threads are using foo now, pushing and popping elements

int size = foo.size();
for (int i=0;i < size;++i)
   do_something(foo[i]);
```

IMO code like this is really bad, because it makes you feel `safe` thinking that monitors will take care of thread-safety for you, while here we have a race condition which is incredibly difficult to spot.

Comment: Concerning #1: I would go even further and claim that putting mutexes and locks inside your class implementation code is a violation of the single responsibility principle.

Comment: It's interesting to note that in your code, you never show the declaration for the mutex.  Things will go badly wrong if different parts of the code use different mutexes to lock a particular `Account` object, so there needs to be a way to find out which mutex corresponds to which object.  My fundamental question is how to do that.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: If the mutex for an object doesn't go in the object, where does it go, and how does code that needs to find the mutex for a specific object find it?

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe The mutex goes paired with the `Account`, but not inside the definition of the type. If you have a vector<Account> you can replace it with a vector< pair<unique_ptr<mutex>,Account> >, or you can use the `Protected` template from StackedCrooked answer, and work with Protecte<Account> objects instead of plain Account objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to associate the locking with the data. In my eyes, stuffing the `mutex` into the object is fine. You could go even further, making the objects essentially into [monitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29): Lock to enter a function member, unlock when leaving.

Answer (score 0):

I believe providing each account with its own lock is fine. It provides a clear signal to any reader of your code that accessing the `Account` is a critical section.

The downside to any solution involving one lock per account is that you have to be mindful of deadlock when you are writing code that manipulates multiple accounts simultaneously. But, the straightforward way to avoid that problem is to limit your interactions to be with one account at a time. This not only avoids potential deadlock problems, it also increases concurrency, since you are not blocking some other thread from being able to access some other account while the current thread is busy with something different.

Your concerns about a consistent view is valid, but can be achieved by logging the operations that are occurring with the current transaction. For example, you can decorate your `deposit()` and `withdraw()` operations with a transaction log.

```
class Account {
  void deposit(const Money &amount);
  void withdraw(const Money &amount);
public:
  void deposit(const Money &amount, Transaction& t) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(m_);
    deposit(amount);
    t.log_deposit(*this, amount);
  }
  void withdraw(const Money &amount, Transaction& t) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(m_);
    withdraw(amount);
    t.log_withdraw(*this, amount);
  }
private:
  std::mutex m_;
};
```

Then, a `transfer` is a logged withdrawal and deposit.

```
void transfer (Account &src, Account &dest, const Money &amount,
               Transaction &t) {
  t.log_transfer(src, dest, amount);
  try {
    src.withdraw(amount, t);
    dest.deposit(amount, t);
    t.log_transfer_complete(src, dest, amount);
  } catch (...) {
    t.log_transfer_fail(src, dest, amount);
    //...
  }
}
```

Note that the idea of a transaction log is orthogonal to how you choose to deploy your locks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is to do as you suggest and use std::lock(), but put it into a friend function. That way you don't need to make the account mutex public. The deposit() and withdraw() functions are not used by the new friend function and will need to separately lock and unlock the mutex. Remember that friend functions are not member functions but do have access to private members.

```
typedef int Money;

class Account {
public:
  Account(Money amount) : balance(amount)
  {
  }

  void deposit(const Money& amount);
  bool withdraw(const Money& amount);

  friend bool transfer(Account& src, Account& dest, const Money& amount)
  {
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> src_lock(src.m, std::defer_lock);
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> dest_lock(dest.m, std::defer_lock);
     std::lock(src_lock, dest_lock);

     if(src.balance >= amount)
     {
        src.balance -= amount;
        dest.balance += amount;
        return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
private:
  std::mutex m;
  Money balance;
};
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it requires modifying the `Account` class each time some new operation needs to be added, e.g., `transferWithSpecialLoggingAndGovernmentOversight`.

Comment: The approach can be extended. The friend can be changed from a function to a class and you can add your new operations to that class. No changes required to the Account class then. You could also change the transfer friend function to a template function and then use tag dispatch to route the calls to the appropriately specialized version. transfer(standard(), acct1, acct2, 100); transfer(special(), acct3, acct4, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions have a problem that data is kept public, thus one can access it without locking the lock.

There is a way to fix that, but you can't use templates and thus have to resort to macros. It is much nicer to implement in C++11 and rather then repeating the whole discussion here, I  link to my implementation on: https://github.com/sveljko/lockstrap